# Marshaling a nested map into JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to marshal this nested map into a JSON string.

```
map[
  description:Foo Bar
  url:http://foobar.co.uk
  theme_color:#1b1b1b
  markdown:kramdown
  sass:map[
    style:compressed
  ]
  collections:map[
    projects:map[
      output:true
      permalink:/project/:path
    ]
    jobs:map[
      output:true
      permalink:/job/:path
    ]
  ]
  title:Foo Bar
  email:foo@foobarco.uk
]
```

(Cleaned up output from `fmt.Printf("%v", m)`)

Initially a config file is read and parsed to produce the map, so I don't know the fields in advance, meaning I can't(?) use a struct.

Unmarshalling from YAML into this map of `map[string]interface{}` works fine, but when I pass this map to `json.Marshal`, I get the following error.

```
json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface{}
```

From reading around, I can see that this error is thrown because JSON only supports string keys. What's confusing me, is that the map above doesn't seem to have any non-string keys.

If I remove the nested `sass` and `collections` keys, it marshals without any issues.

Is it possible to do some sanity check on the map to confirm that all the keys are infact `string` and not just `interface{}` looking like strings?

Comment: Erm, that is NOT a valid map...

Comment: It's not a literal, it's the printed output after the map has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the sub-maps are being created as map[interface{}]interface{} by the YAML parser.

Print out your map with "%#v" instead of "%v" and you will see the types.

[Here's an example](http://play.golang.org/p/OUlMlv0dpu)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := map[string]interface{}{
        "A": map[interface{}]interface{}{
            "B": 123,
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",a)
}
```

Produces:

```
map[string]interface {}{"A":map[interface {}]interface {}{"B":123}}
```

Comment: It is the reason, not a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `github.com/json-iterator/go` package instead of `encode.json`. It can encode `map[interface{}]interface{}` to `JSON`.

https://github.com/json-iterator/go

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use or get inspired by this package:

https://github.com/ghodss/yaml